# Android : stopping a thread that sends data to a server

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am currently working on a time consuming project and I am stumbling on many little difficulties that make my life really difficult...
I submit to you my last problem : I have created a thread to send data to a server in order to put it in a database. It works but only the first time because my thread is not stopped.

Here is the code :

```
threadHttp = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
                try{
                    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.seismdetector.info/reception.php");
                    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); // C'est la liste qui contiendra les couples champ/valeur
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "android"));
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
        }
    };
```

So when I hit the button that starts this thread once it's okay but the second time the application crashes because it cannot launch a thread that's still running.

I tried such things as

```
if(threadHttp.isAlive())
    threadHttp.interrupt();
```

but it doesn't work either.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: In the code you post, you are creating a new thread, but never starting it.  If you feel you have a problem trying to re-start a thread, then post the code which you believe does this, as the code you have provided does not.  For what you seem to be trying to do, an AsyncTask might be a good solution - by basically letting the implementation of the AsyncTask worry about choosing or creating an appropriate background thread to get the job done.

Comment: I just do this :


    public void onClick(View v){
 switch(v.getId()){
 case R.id.sendButton:
    threadHttp.start();
        ...
        }
}

Could you indicate me a good place where to learn how to use AsyncTask ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Consider the documentation thereof, or search for it here.

Comment: Thread.start() can only be called once. interrupt() or join() would not help. Create another thread instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `AsyncTask` class for this:

```
private class ExampleThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.seismdetector.info/reception.php");
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); // C'est la liste qui contiendra les couples champ/valeur
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "android"));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {}

}
```

To start the thread:

```
ExampleThread thread = new ExampleThread();
thread.execute();
```

To stop the thread:

```
thread.cancel();
```